# awk extract lines that both patterns matched are true

Tags: text-processing, awk, text

how can I alter below code, in order to print the lines that match the following criteria, but only when both conditions are true?

the lines i need to extract have to comply with this:
print only the line that matches patterna, if you find , a line that meets the patternb criteria.

```
awk '/patterna/ || /patternb/ { print > "patternapatternb.txt" }' inputfile
```

input file
patterna this
patternb that
patterna that
patterna that
anotherpattern
patterna anotherthis
patternb anotherthat

output patternapatternb.txt:
patterna this
patternb that
patterna anotherthis
patternb anotherthat

and how this could be achieved for many pairs of patterns, in order to be able to write each pair's output, to a different file

Comment: `... exp && exp...`

Comment: awk '/patterna/ && /patternb/ { print > "patternapatternb.txt" } ' inputfile  this will return only those lines that meet both criteria. i need to extract the lines hat meet the first pattern, and those that meet the second pattern, but only when both are true...

Comment: I cant see the difference: `&&` is the and operator and fits your description.

Comment: i need to extract the lines that meet the above criteria, in a sequential way.  ie only when patterna, is true, AND followed by a true patternb  i use the or operator, because i need both lines in the output...

Comment: Your output is not correct based on your criteria. You say that `patternb` must be found even if it is not the next line after `patterna`. In that case, the second occurrence of `patterna this` should pair with `patternb anotherthat`. I suspect you have some more conditions in mind that you are not specifying, such as that patterns cannot cross: a `patternb` must be found after `patterna`, but before `patterna` occurs again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` processes each record (by default, a record is a line) separately - to apply conditions spanning adjacent lines you can use the `getline` function to read the next record and test that against your second pattern:

```
awk '/patterna/ { 
  a=$0
  if (getline > 0 && $0 ~ /patternb/) {
    print a
    print
  }
}' inputfile
```

Alternatively, you could consider using `sed`

```
sed -n '/patterna/ {$!N; /\npatternb/p}' inputfile
```

---

If you want to print the first match of `/patternb/` after each match of `/patterna/`, preceded by its `/patterna/`, then you can make a *stateful* parser by setting a flag each time you match `/patterna/` and unsetting it at each `/patternb/`:

```
awk '
  /patterna/ {
    a=1; lasta=$0; next;
  } 
  /patternb/ && a==1 {
     a=0; print lasta; print;
  }' inputfile
```

Comment: this only works if the line with patternb, is always next to the line with patterna, i need a solution, that will work for the next instance, of patternb found

Comment: @Perina imho that was not at all clear in your question. See update.

Comment: you are correct, my fault

Comment: how then i could reuse the above,  awk '
  /patterna/ {
    a=1; lasta=$0; next;
  } 
  /patternb/ && a==1 {
     a=0; print lasta; print;
  }' inputfile  awk '
  /patterna2/ {
    a=1; lasta=$0; next;
  } 
  /patternb2/ && a==1 {
     a=0; print lasta; print;
  }' inputfile  and output to say two different files the matches of patterna and b, and then the matches of patterna2 and b2

Comment: @Perina please [edit] your original question to **clearly** state **all** your requirements - comments are not the right place for that

Answer (score 1):

Squeaky clean solution in using [TXR](http://nongnu.org.txr), with no explicit state manipulation or side effects other than output:

```
@(repeat)
patterna @this
@  (repeat)
patterna @other
@    (fail)
@  (last :mandatory)
patternb @that
@  (end)
@  (output)
patterna @this
patternb @that
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr pairs.txr data
patterna this
patternb that
patterna anotherthis
patternb anotherthat
```

In this solution we try to capture this requirement: keyword `patternb` is to be found after a line with `patterna`. It need not be the immediately following line. However, `patternb` must occur before another line occurs which has `patterna`: between a given `patterna` line and its matching `patternb` pair line, there cannot be another `patterna` line.

The internal iteration:

```
@  (repeat)
patterna @other
@    (fail)
@  (last :mandatory)
patternb @that
@  (end)
```

scans the input, looking for two things: a match on

```
patterna @other
```

or the mandatory terminating match

```
patternb @that
```

However, if the `patterna @other` is found, the very next directive after that is `@(fail)` which causes the repeat to fail. (Repeat establishes an implicit `@(block)` and `@(fail)` causes the inner-most enclosing block to terminate as a failed match.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on your more comprehensive explanation you can use pcregrep

```
pcregrep -M 'patterna(.*\n)patternb' inputfile > patternapatternb.txt
```

This oneliner will give you

```
cat patternapatternb.txt
patterna this
patternb that
patterna another this
patternb another that
```

*previous reply*

I used this oneliner ...

```
 awk '/patterna/ && /patternb/ {print > "patternapatterb.txt" } ' inputfile
```

And this inputfile

```
cat inputfile
patterna    patternb    this
patterna    patterna    that
```

The results are

```
cat patternapatterb.txt
patterna    patternb    this
```

This appears to be exactly that which you requested (you said "but only when both are true"); however if we have misunderstood your request, please let us know.

If you want to match either patterna or patternb, you can use egrep

```
 egrep "patterna||patternb" inputfile > patternapatternb.txt
```

Comment: sorry for not a clear explanation from myside